# Wazuh dashboard - I can't connect to web interface dashboard from another device in same network

Tags: centos7, wazuh

I have wazuh indexer, server, dashboard on one device, all was installed with wazuh installer on wazuh official webpage. All is working quite well, but I can't connect to web interface of dashboard from another device in the same network.

I allowed all useful ports on firewall, but it's always timed-out, or server refused. So I stoped firewall for a moment, but it still doesn't work. I can ping between devices and wazuh agents are communicating. I checked all .conf and .yml files by wazuh guide, but they are fine I guess. I did some research on internet, but I didn't find a thing.

Opensearch_dashboards.yml

```
server.port: 443
opensearch.ssl.verificationMode: certificate
opensearch.username: kibanaserver
opensearch.password: kibanaserver
opensearch.requestHeadersAllowlist: ["securitytenant","Authorization"]
opensearch_security.multitenancy.enabled: false
opensearch_security.readonly_mode.roles: ["kibana_read_only"]
server.ssl.enabled: true
server.ssl.key: "/etc/wazuh-dashboard/certs/dashboard-key.pem"
server.ssl.certificate: "/etc/wazuh-dashboard/certs/dashboard.pem"
opensearch.ssl.certificateAuthorities: ["/etc/wazuh-dashboard/certs/root-ca.pem"]
uiSettings.overrides.defaultRoute: /app/wazuh
opensearch_security.cookie.secure: true
server.host: 192.168.1.56
opensearch.hosts: https://192.168.1.56:9200
```

Wazuh.yml (without # fillers)

```
hosts:
  - default:
      url: https://192.168.1.56
      port: 55000
      username: wazuh-wui
      password: "wazuh-wui"
      run_as: false
```

ossec.conf (agent config, i think can't be problem in my thing)

```
<!--
  Wazuh - Manager - Default configuration for centos 7.9
  More info at: https://documentation.wazuh.com
  Mailing list: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/wazuh
-->

<ossec_config>
  <global>
    <jsonout_output>yes</jsonout_output>
    <alerts_log>yes</alerts_log>
    <logall>no</logall>
    <logall_json>no</logall_json>
    <email_notification>no</email_notification>
    <smtp_server>smtp.example.wazuh.com</smtp_server>
    <email_from>wazuh@example.wazuh.com</email_from>
    <email_to>recipient@example.wazuh.com</email_to>
    <email_maxperhour>12</email_maxperhour>
    <email_log_source>alerts.log</email_log_source>
    <agents_disconnection_time>10m</agents_disconnection_time>
    <agents_disconnection_alert_time>0</agents_disconnection_alert_time>
  </global>

  <alerts>
    <log_alert_level>3</log_alert_level>
    <email_alert_level>12</email_alert_level>
  </alerts>

  <!-- Choose between "plain", "json", or "plain,json" for the format of internal logs -->
  <logging>
    <log_format>plain</log_format>
  </logging>

  <remote>
    <connection>secure</connection>
    <port>1514</port>
    <protocol>tcp</protocol>
    <queue_size>131072</queue_size>
  </remote>

  <!-- Policy monitoring -->
  <rootcheck>
    <disabled>no</disabled>
    <check_files>yes</check_files>
    <check_trojans>yes</check_trojans>
    <check_dev>yes</check_dev>
    <check_sys>yes</check_sys>
    <check_pids>yes</check_pids>
    <check_ports>yes</check_ports>
    <check_if>yes</check_if>

    <!-- Frequency that rootcheck is executed - every 12 hours -->
    <frequency>43200</frequency>

    <rootkit_files>etc/rootcheck/rootkit_files.txt</rootkit_files>
    <rootkit_trojans>etc/rootcheck/rootkit_trojans.txt</rootkit_trojans>

    <skip_nfs>yes</skip_nfs>
  </rootcheck>

  <wodle name="cis-cat">
    <disabled>yes</disabled>
    <timeout>1800</timeout>
    <interval>1d</interval>
    <scan-on-start>yes</scan-on-start>

    <java_path>wodles/java</java_path>
    <ciscat_path>wodles/ciscat</ciscat_path>
  </wodle>

  <!-- Osquery integration -->
  <wodle name="osquery">
    <disabled>yes</disabled>
    <run_daemon>yes</run_daemon>
    <log_path>/var/log/osquery/osqueryd.results.log</log_path>
    <config_path>/etc/osquery/osquery.conf</config_path>
    <add_labels>yes</add_labels>
  </wodle>

  <!-- System inventory -->
  <wodle name="syscollector">
    <disabled>no</disabled>
    <interval>1h</interval>
    <scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>
    <hardware>yes</hardware>
    <os>yes</os>
    <network>yes</network>
    <packages>yes</packages>
    <ports all="no">yes</ports>
    <processes>yes</processes>

    <!-- Database synchronization settings -->
    <synchronization>
      <max_eps>10</max_eps>
    </synchronization>
  </wodle>

  <sca>
    <enabled>yes</enabled>
    <scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>
    <interval>12h</interval>
    <skip_nfs>yes</skip_nfs>
  </sca>

  <vulnerability-detector>
    <enabled>yes</enabled>
    <interval>5m</interval>
    <min_full_scan_interval>6h</min_full_scan_interval>
    <run_on_start>yes</run_on_start>

    <!-- Ubuntu OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="canonical">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <os>trusty</os>
      <os>xenial</os>
      <os>bionic</os>
      <os>focal</os>
      <os>jammy</os>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- Debian OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="debian">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <os>buster</os>
      <os>bullseye</os>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- RedHat OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="redhat">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <os>5</os>
      <os>6</os>
      <os>7</os>
      <os>8</os>
      <os>9</os>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- Amazon Linux OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="alas">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <os>amazon-linux</os>
      <os>amazon-linux-2</os>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- SUSE OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="suse">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <os>11-server</os>
      <os>11-desktop</os>
      <os>12-server</os>
      <os>12-desktop</os>
      <os>15-server</os>
      <os>15-desktop</os>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- Arch OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="arch">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- Windows OS vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="msu">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

    <!-- Aggregate vulnerabilities -->
    <provider name="nvd">
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <update_from_year>2010</update_from_year>
      <update_interval>1h</update_interval>
    </provider>

  </vulnerability-detector>

  <!-- File integrity monitoring -->
  <syscheck>
    <disabled>no</disabled>

    <!-- Frequency that syscheck is executed default every 12 hours -->
    <frequency>43200</frequency>

    <scan_on_start>yes</scan_on_start>

    <!-- Generate alert when new file detected -->
    <alert_new_files>yes</alert_new_files>

    <!-- Don't ignore files that change more than 'frequency' times -->
    <auto_ignore frequency="10" timeframe="3600">no</auto_ignore>

    <!-- Directories to check  (perform all possible verifications) -->
    <directories>/etc,/usr/bin,/usr/sbin</directories>
    <directories>/bin,/sbin,/boot</directories>

    <!-- Files/directories to ignore -->
    <ignore>/etc/mtab</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/hosts.deny</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/mail/statistics</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/random-seed</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/random.seed</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/adjtime</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/httpd/logs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/utmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/wtmpx</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/cups/certs</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/dumpdates</ignore>
    <ignore>/etc/svc/volatile</ignore>

    <!-- File types to ignore -->
    <ignore type="sregex">.log$|.swp$</ignore>

    <!-- Check the file, but never compute the diff -->
    <nodiff>/etc/ssl/private.key</nodiff>

    <skip_nfs>yes</skip_nfs>
    <skip_dev>yes</skip_dev>
    <skip_proc>yes</skip_proc>
    <skip_sys>yes</skip_sys>

    <!-- Nice value for Syscheck process -->
    <process_priority>10</process_priority>

    <!-- Maximum output throughput -->
    <max_eps>100</max_eps>

    <!-- Database synchronization settings -->
    <synchronization>
      <enabled>yes</enabled>
      <interval>5m</interval>
      <max_interval>1h</max_interval>
      <max_eps>10</max_eps>
    </synchronization>
  </syscheck>

  <!-- Active response -->
  <global>
    <white_list>127.0.0.1</white_list>
    <white_list>^localhost.localdomain$</white_list>
    <white_list>172.16.7.65</white_list>
    <white_list>172.16.7.66</white_list>
  </global>

  <command>
    <name>disable-account</name>
    <executable>disable-account</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>restart-wazuh</name>
    <executable>restart-wazuh</executable>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>firewall-drop</name>
    <executable>firewall-drop</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>host-deny</name>
    <executable>host-deny</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>route-null</name>
    <executable>route-null</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>win_route-null</name>
    <executable>route-null.exe</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <command>
    <name>netsh</name>
    <executable>netsh.exe</executable>
    <timeout_allowed>yes</timeout_allowed>
  </command>

  <!--
  <active-response>
    active-response options here
  </active-response>
  -->

  <!-- Log analysis -->
  <localfile>
    <log_format>command</log_format>
    <command>df -P</command>
    <frequency>360</frequency>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>full_command</log_format>
    <command>netstat -tulpn | sed 's/\([[:alnum:]]\+\)\ \+[[:digit:]]\+\ \+[[:digit:]]\+\ \+\(.*\):\([[:digit:]]*\)\ \+\([0-9\.\:\*]\+\).\+\ \([[:digit:]]*\/[[:alnum:]\-]*\).*/\1 \2 == \3 == \4 \5/' | sort -k 4 -g | sed 's/ == \(.*\) ==/:\1/' | sed 1,2d</command>
    <alias>netstat listening ports</alias>
    <frequency>360</frequency>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>full_command</log_format>
    <command>last -n 20</command>
    <frequency>360</frequency>
  </localfile>

  <ruleset>
    <!-- Default ruleset -->
    <decoder_dir>ruleset/decoders</decoder_dir>
    <rule_dir>ruleset/rules</rule_dir>
    <rule_exclude>0215-policy_rules.xml</rule_exclude>
    <list>etc/lists/audit-keys</list>
    <list>etc/lists/amazon/aws-eventnames</list>
    <list>etc/lists/security-eventchannel</list>

    <!-- User-defined ruleset -->
    <decoder_dir>etc/decoders</decoder_dir>
    <rule_dir>etc/rules</rule_dir>
  </ruleset>

  <rule_test>
    <enabled>yes</enabled>
    <threads>1</threads>
    <max_sessions>64</max_sessions>
    <session_timeout>15m</session_timeout>
  </rule_test>

  <!-- Configuration for wazuh-authd -->
  <auth>
    <disabled>no</disabled>
    <port>1515</port>
    <use_source_ip>no</use_source_ip>
    <purge>yes</purge>
    <use_password>no</use_password>
    <ciphers>HIGH:!ADH:!EXP:!MD5:!RC4:!3DES:!CAMELLIA:@STRENGTH</ciphers>
    <!-- <ssl_agent_ca></ssl_agent_ca> -->
    <ssl_verify_host>no</ssl_verify_host>
    <ssl_manager_cert>etc/sslmanager.cert</ssl_manager_cert>
    <ssl_manager_key>etc/sslmanager.key</ssl_manager_key>
    <ssl_auto_negotiate>no</ssl_auto_negotiate>
  </auth>

  <cluster>
    <name>wazuh</name>
    <node_name>node01</node_name>
    <node_type>master</node_type>
    <key></key>
    <port>1516</port>
    <bind_addr>0.0.0.0</bind_addr>
    <nodes>
        <node>NODE_IP</node>
    </nodes>
    <hidden>no</hidden>
    <disabled>yes</disabled>
  </cluster>

</ossec_config>

<ossec_config>
  <localfile>
    <log_format>audit</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/audit/audit.log</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/ossec/logs/active-responses.log</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/messages</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/secure</location>
  </localfile>

  <localfile>
    <log_format>syslog</log_format>
    <location>/var/log/maillog</location>
  </localfile>

</ossec_config>
```